# $X$ an integral element over $K[X^d]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I'm currently redoing some homework for my algebra test and I came across a task that wants me to find a noether normalization of $k[X]$, where $k$ is a field. The proof I know uses the argument, that $X$ is an integral element over $k[X^d]$ for $d$ element of IN. However I don't remember why exactly that is the case. I'd be very thankful for some advices regarding this problem, thank you in advance for answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a solution of the monic polynomial equation
$$y^d-X^d=0$$
where the indeterminate is $y$ and $X^d$ is the element of the ring.

Comment: But why would that still be an element of K[X^d]? The element y shouldn't be an element of it since I only adjointed X^d to it should it? @Matt Samuel

Comment: @eu It's not an element of $K[X^d] $. It's an integral element over it, which need not be contained in the ring.

Comment: Maybe I am getting something wrong here, but in order for y to be the indeterminate, it also has to be adjointed hasn't it? Therefore I would need to talk about something like K[X^d][y] which would be a ring with 2 variables wouldn't it? @Matt Samuel

Comment: @eu An integral element is a root of a monic polynomial with coefficients in the ring. I chose $y$ as the indeterminate. It's a polynomial in $y$ with coefficients in $K[X^d] $, and $X$ is a root of this polynomial.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I had an error in my thought process and mixed something up. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my questions, you helped me out a lot!

Comment: @eu27 No problem.